# Get status of Paypal NVP correlationid

Tags: paypal, nvp

I have a transaction with "Correlationid" with Paypal's Express Checkout NVP API.  How can I get the details for this correlationid as to whether the transaction was completed or denied?

Answer (score 0):

The CorrelationID is pretty much useless as the transactionID is used in reference lookup such as this. The best solution here to do is run the GETTRANSACTIONDETAILS API call for Express Checkout using the:

PAYMENTSTATUS   Status of the payment.

It is one of the following values:
None — No status

**Canceled-Reversal** — A reversal has been canceled, for example, when you win a dispute and the funds for the reversal have been returned to you.

**Completed** — The payment has been completed, and the funds have been added successfully to your account balance.

**Denied** — You denied the payment. This happens only if the payment was previously pending because of possible reasons described for the PendingReason element.

**Expired** — The authorization period for this payment has been reached.

**Failed** — The payment has failed. This happens only if the payment was made from your buyer's bank account.

**In-Progress** — The transaction has not terminated, for example, an authorization may be awaiting completion.

**Partially-Refunded** — The payment has been partially refunded.

**Pending** — The payment is pending. See the PendingReason field for more information.

**Refunded** — You refunded the payment.

**Reversed** — A payment was reversed due to a chargeback or other type of reversal. The funds have been removed from your account balance and returned to the buyer. The reason for the reversal is specified in the ReasonCode element.

**Processed** — A payment has been accepted.

**Voided** — An authorization for this transaction has been voided.

Here is a document to assist you with this call and parameters:
[GetTransactionsDetails API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/)

Comment: Problem is that I am using Magento and Express checkout.  Customer redirects to checkout page with API request "SetExpressCheckout" and response including "token", "correlationid" and "ack => success", but it never comes back to my website so I don't have the transaction id for it.  Now I have no clue what happened and why customer could not complete the payment.

Comment: Ok, this is different. If the payment wasn't completed, you should still have a response from the GETEXPRESSCHECKOUT API (when customer clicks continue -redirect to site) in your Log files. Turn on debugging in magento in the PayPal Express Checkout section. Test,  and check the response or you can run a HTTP sniffer on the payment request to see what kind of response you're getting on the call.

Comment: I already have debug mode enabled and I have seen that "GetExpressCheckoutDetails" is called only when customer comes back after authorization to my website for order review step.  If the customer leaves from Paypal's billing page, no API call is made for "GetExpressCheckoutDetails".